# Generate a GeoJSON heatmap using MongoDB map/reduce

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid, heatmap

I am visualising annual UK film screening using a javascript map that takes GeoJSON as an input. You can see it working for 2011 data here: http://screened2011.herokuapp.com

The generation of the GeoJSON is very inefficient - often taking 5+ seconds per "tile".

I have a Ruby app which queries MongoDB for a set of "screenings" within a bounding box (as requested by the JS) and then generates a two-dimensional array representing the total number of screenings that occurred within each of a 16x16. This is apparently the bottleneck - it's hitting the server and pulling down all of these screenings.

I'd like to replace this with a map/reduce query that aggregates the count of all screenings within a bounding box into a 16x16 array of values, but I'm not having much success - it's quite the task for my first map/reduce!

Here's a simplified version of my code with unrelated stuff taken out (it's awful, and if this weren't a hack coming to an end, I'd refactor):

```
get :boxed, :map => "/screenings/year/:year/quadrant/:area/bbox/:bbox", :provides => [:json, :jsonp], :cache => false do
    box = parameter_box(params[:bbox]) # returns [[minx,miny],[maxx,maxy]]
    year = params[:year].to_i
    screenings = Screening.where(:location.within(:box) => box).where(:year => year)
    jsonp Screening.heatmap(screenings, box, 16)
 end

def self.heatmap screenings, box, scale
  grid = []
  min_x = box[0][0]
  min_y = box[0][1]
  max_x = box[1][0]
  max_y = box[1][1]
  box_width = max_x.to_f - min_x.to_f
  box_height = max_y.to_f - min_y.to_f

  return [] if box_width == 0 || box_height == 0

  # Set up an empty GeoJSON-style array to hold the results
  scalef = scale.to_f
  (0..(scale - 1)).each do |i| 
    grid[i] = []
    (0..(scale - 1)).each do |j| 

      box_min_x = min_x + (i * ( box_width / scalef  ))
      box_max_x = min_x + ((i + 1) * ( box_width / scalef  ))
      box_min_y = min_y + (j * ( box_height / scalef  ))
      box_max_y = min_y + ((j + 1) * ( box_height / scalef  ))

      grid[i][j] = { 
        :count => 0,
        #:id => "#{box_min_x}_#{box_max_x}_#{box_min_y}_#{box_max_y}",
        :coordinates => [
          [
            [box_min_x,box_min_y], [box_min_x, box_max_y], [box_max_x, box_max_y], [box_max_x, box_min_y], [box_min_x,box_min_y]
          ]
        ]
      } 
    end
  end

  # This loop is the bottleneck and I'd like to replace with a map-reduce
  screenings.only(:location, :total_showings).each do |screening|
    x = (scale * ((screening.location[0] - min_x) / box_width)).floor
    y = (scale * ((screening.location[1] - min_y) / box_height)).floor
    raise if x > (scale - 1)
    raise if y > (scale - 1)
    grid[x][y][:count] += screening.total_showings.to_i
  end

  # This converts the resulting 16x16 into GeoJSON
  places = []
  grid.each do |x|
    x.each do |p|
      if p[:count].to_i > 0
        properties = {}
        properties[:total_showings] = p[:count]
        places << {
          "id" => p[:id],
          "type" => "Feature",
          "geometry" => {
            "type" => "Polygon",
            "coordinates" => p[:coordinates]
          },
          "properties"=> properties
        }
      end
    end
  end

  {
    "type" => "FeatureCollection",
    "features" => places
  }
end
```

I'm using Mongoid, so I could chain a mapreduce onto the screenings query, and I'm hoping that this would greatly speed up the process - but how should I go about getting something like the following to pass into this function?:

```
[
  [1,20000,30,3424,53,66,7586,54543,76764,4322,7664,43242,43,435,32,643],
  ...
]
```

...based on several million records each in this structure (essentially summing the total_showings) for each one within a bounding box:

```
{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('50e481e653e6dfbc92057e8d'),
 "created_at"=>2013-01-02 18:52:22 +0000,
 "ended_at"=>Thu, 07 Jun 2012 00:00:00 +0100,
 "events"=>["10044735484"],
 "film_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f96a91153e6df5ebc001afe'),
 "genre_ids"=>[],
 "location"=>[-2.003309596016, 52.396317185921],
 "performance_id"=>"9001923080",
 "specialised"=>false,
 "started_at"=>Fri, 01 Jun 2012 00:00:00 +0100,
 "total_showings"=>1,
 "updated_at"=>2013-01-02 18:52:22 +0000,
 "venue_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4f9500bf53e6df004000034d'),
 "week"=>nil,
 "year"=>2012}
```

Thanks in advance folks!